# awscli fails to execute within python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, amazon-web-services, centos7

I'm really bad with python.  This is on a CentOS7 vm

**Problem:**

When trying to use `awscli` in a python virtual environment, I get an error:

```
(python3ve) [user@ncwv-jlnxnode01 ~]$ aws --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv/python3ve/bin/aws", line 27, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/user/venv/python3ve/bin/aws", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/home/user/venv/python3ve/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 69, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File "/home/user/venv/python3ve/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 79, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=session.get_component('event_emitter'))
  File "/home/user/venv/python3ve/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 44, in load_plugins
    modules = _import_plugins(plugin_mapping)
  File "/home/user/venv/python3ve/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 61, in _import_plugins
    module = __import__(path, fromlist=[module])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/root/'
```

ultimately i'm trying to put together a step by step method in an ansible playbook for not only installing `awscli`, but also `awscli-plugin-endpoint`, so i'd prefer to install this through pip instead of the centos repos and instead of just downloading the binaries.

**Installation Steps:**

1. remove python3 and everything python3 related on the system.

```
~$ rm -rf ~/venv/python3ve/
~$ sudo yum remove -y python3
~$ sudo yum autoremove -y
~$ sudo find / -name "python3*" > ~/file
~$ sudo xargs rm -r ~/file  (missing the arrow because stackoverflow formatting is freaking out with it)
```

2. install

```
~$ sudo yum install -y python3
~$ /usr/bin/python3 -m venv ~/venv/python3ve
~$ source ~/venv/python3ve/bin/activate
~$ ~/venv/python3ve/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
~$ ~/venv/python3ve/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade awscli
~$ which aws
~/venv/python3ve/bin/aws
~$ aws --version
---output is in the problem description above---
```

suggestions?

Comment: Any particular reason for running awscli in a venv? Current versions of the awscli include Python.

Comment: ive always had permissions problems with awscli when the OS has multiple versions of python, like centos7 ends up with (python 2.7 by default, but awscli and pip now require python3+), so i was leaning towards using venv to isolate everything into a single place, the python exec (or at least a symlink of), the modules, etc.
I also need to install awscli-plugin-endpoint so i needed to get pip working properly to install modules.

I've also had permissions trouble when using awscli installed from the centos repo or a precompiled binary and trying to use awscli-plugin-endpoint.

Comment: Use the current, bundled awscli. It includes everything it needs. Your CentOS AMIs shouldn't contain Python 2.x, ideally, because it's EOL.

Comment: Its an esxi vm, not a aws ec2 instance.  so the OS is an old centos7 with python 2.7 preinstalled still.

Answer (score 1):

ultimately found that the error was stemming from my `~/.aws/config` which I wasnt removing when I reinstalled.  that had a reference to the plugin not yet installed and also the old site-packages path (pre venv)

```
cli_legacy_plugin_path=/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
endpoint = awscli_plugin_endpoint
```

Once I removed those, it worked fine again.

```
~$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.24.10 Python/3.6.8 Linux/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.26.10
```

The error was referencing `/root/` because of how `_import_plugins` within `/awscli/plugin.py` splits the path based on `.` if present

`module = path.rsplit('.', 1)`